# How to move one specific commit to another branch?

Tags: git, github, branch, commit

so lets say I have 2 branches : Master , dev . And commits look like this:

Master : A-B-C

dev:   A-B-C-D-E-F

I want to move just the E commit from dev branch to Master like this :

Master : A-B-C-E

dev:     A-B-C-D-E-F

I know this can cause problems if there are some changes in commit D that are required for commit E, but in my case I am certain that commit E doesnt have anything to do with commit D.

And after some time when D and F commits are also ready to be moved to Master branch I want to merge them without any problems like this :

Master : A-B-C-D-E-F

dev:     A-B-C-D-E-F

I can understand if there is no easy way to do this because this wouldnt make sense in most of the cases out there . Open to any solutions that can help my specific case where I know for sure that commit E doesnt have anything to do with commit D .

Comment: Which commit is master and dev pointing to at the start?

Comment: I dont seem to fully understand your question , I am sorry , quite new to git .

Comment: In git, branches are only labels for a specific commit. So `A-B-C-D-E-F` isn't the branch, but a tree of commits. The confusion comes from the fact that `master` might be pointing at A or F.

Comment: Consider watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4?

Comment: Alright I understand now , that was a great explanation . Master is pointing at C dev is at F . With that information I think what I am asking for doesnt make any sense . I had no idea branches were just pointers . I wanted Master to point at E and skip D which might not make any sense now that I understand that branches are pointers . Well my problem is still there and dont know how to fix it .

Comment: You could have master and dev share A-B-C, but then they'd diverge and master could have E-F, and dev could have D-E'-F' (note that they're not the exact same commits, but copies)

Comment: So just manually copy changes that are in commit E and make a completely new commit on master , which will have same changes but just a different commit . Did I get that right?

Comment: If Dev points to F, and master is points to C. You should be able to cherry pick E onto master. `git switch master; git cherry pick E`? (replace E with the hash of the correct commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `cherry-pick` on master:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick E
```

Which will create a copy of commit E on master (as commit `E'` if you will). New history:

```
Master : A-B-C-E'
dev: A-B-C-D-E-F
```

But note that it will not be easily possible to have master as `A-B-C-D-E-F`. Having master as `A-B-C-E'-D'-F'` is easy however. Simply cherry-pick `D` and `F` when you need them. Or merge branch `dev` fully. Git should be smart enough to detect that master already contains a copy of `E`.